# In Pandas, how to merge multiple CSV files with a unnamed date index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bunch of file all having the same format, note the first column does not have a name.

```
        USD_EUR USD_JPY USD_GBP USD_AUD USD_CAD USD_CHF USD_HKD
1/1/2000    0.995421063 102.2596058 0.618853275 1.535138364 1.454111089 1.597750348 7.767569182
1/2/2000    0.995421063 102.2596058 0.618853275 1.535138364 1.454111089 1.597750348 7.767569182
1/3/2000    0.991080278 101.8334985 0.619028741 1.520911794 1.444697721 1.589990089 7.792269574
1/4/2000    0.970402717 102.7462397 0.610965551 1.52130034  1.449393498 1.557787482 7.782726832
1/5/2000    0.964506173 103.5300926 0.609953704 1.521315586 1.453028549 1.548996914 7.776716821
1/6/2000    0.962649211 104.6592222 0.606661533 1.523681171 1.452733924 1.546784752 7.782345014
```

How do I load all of them into a dataframe with the date as index?  Here is what I have:

```
files = glob.glob(f"./Data_Forex/*")
if(ForexCache is None):
    ForexCache = []
    for file in files:
        filename = Path(file).stem 
        df_fx = pd.read_csv(f"{file}")
        df_fx.iloc[:,0] = df_fx.iloc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d"))
        df_fx.set_index(df_fx.index, inplace=True)
        ForexCache.append(df_fx)
    ForexCache = functools.reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer'), ForexCache)
```

The result is a bunch of empty rows with the index date but no values and all the columns are duplicated for each file, so the columns didn't get merged, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to concatenate, not merge. [Official documentation guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: Got it, do you want to write a answer?  I'll write one myself if you do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that all your files are in `root_folder`, you can get a `DataFrame` with the content of all your files and sorted by date in this way:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root_folder, filename), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
    for filename in next(os.walk(root_folder))[2]
]).sort_index()
```